# Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem Returns Nothing When Items Exist

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm experimenting with Azure Resource Manager backups and restores using Recovery Services vaults in "Pay-As-You-Go" subscriptions.  I am using very simple code that as far as I can tell is right out of MS documentation. I can get a vault object and I can get a container, but when I attempt to get any items out of any container, Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem always returns nothing, even when I know there are items in there and the Azure RM GUI confirms this. "Returns nothing" means if I assign the result to a variable it is empty/null, and if I try to output to the console there is no output.

I have had the same result with two different subscriptions, with different vaults, vm's and backup items, and from two different computers. I have re-installed modules on one machine and installed modules from scratch on the other.  Using the -Debug switch for the Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem command appears to show the items being returned, with an OK result and no errors.  Powershell code appears below, and -Debug output appears after that.  The kicker is, this exact code was working on 2/7/17, no kidding.  I'm about out of ideas at this point so any help would be appreciated.

Update: We have found that when we use the -FriendlyName parameter for the Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer the problem occurs, but if we pipe the output through | Where-Object { $_.FriendlyName -eq $vmName } the problem does not occur.  We have opened a case with MSFT.

```
$vaultName = 'somevault'
$resourceGroupName = 'somerg'
$vmName = 'testvm'

$vault = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name $vaultName -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName;
Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext -Vault $vault

$container = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer  -ContainerType AzureVM –Status Registered -FriendlyName $vmName
#output of this cmdlet is empty
Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem –Container $container  -Debug
```

Debug output:

```
DEBUG: ============================ HTTP RESPONSE ============================

Status Code:
OK

Headers:
Pragma                        : no-cache
x-ms-request-id               : xxx
x-ms-client-request-id        : xxx
Strict-Transport-Security     : max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-reads: 14930
x-ms-correlation-request-id   : xxx
x-ms-routing-request-id       : WESTUS:xxx
Cache-Control                 : no-cache
Date                          : Sat, 11 Feb 2017 19:39:07 GMT
Server                        : Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-Powered-By                  : ASP.NET

Body:

{
  "value": [
    {
      "id": "/Subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/VS-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-Group/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/vault273/backupFabrics/Azure/protectionContainers/IaasVM
Container;iaasvmcontainerv2;VS-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-Group;testvm/protectedItems/VM;iaasvmcontainerv2;VS-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-Group;testvm",
      "name": "iaasvmcontainerv2;VS-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-Group;testvm",
      "type": "Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/backupFabrics/protectionContainers/protectedItems",
      "properties": {
        "friendlyName": "testvm",
        "virtualMachineId": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/VS-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-Group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm",
        "protectionStatus": "Healthy",
        "protectionState": "Protected",
        "healthStatus": "Passed",
        "healthDetails": [
          {
            "code": 400239,
            "title": "IaasVmHealthGreenDefault",
            "message": "Backup pre-check status of this virtual machine is OK.",
            "recommendations": []
          }
        ],
        "lastBackupStatus": "Completed",
        "lastBackupTime": "2017-02-11T15:11:12.2071619Z",
        "protectedItemDataId": "70368936803029",
        "protectedItemType": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
        "backupManagementType": "AzureIaasVM",
        "workloadType": "VM",
        "containerName": "iaasvmcontainerv2;VS-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-Group;testvm",
        "sourceResourceId": "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/VS-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-Group/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm",
        "policyId": "/Subscriptions/xxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/VS-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-Group/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/vault273/backupPolicies/DailyPolicy",
        "policyName": "DailyPolicy",
        "lastRecoveryPoint": "2017-02-11T15:12:16.7410628Z"
      }
    }
  ]
}


DEBUG: AzureQoSEvent: CommandName - Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem; IsSuccess - True; Duration - 00:00:02.3527163; Exception - ;
```

Comment: try another pc? the reinstalling azure module?

Comment: Should have mentioned that I've run the same code with the same result on two different client machines, one Windows 10 and one Windows 8.1.  With the latter, I installed all the AzureRm modules fresh.

Comment: What your Azure Powershell version? You could check use `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` . My test version is `3.4.0`.I use your cmdlets except `Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem –Container $container[0] -WorkloadType "AzureVM" `.

Comment: @Walter - MSFT  I am using version 3.5.0.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue (also on various PCs) and worked around it by passing a different parameters set. I'm not using the Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupContainer to get a reference to the container. Instead, I'm directly calling Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem with the container name. This only works when you pass the parameter -BackupManagementType AzureVM.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId <myguid>

Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVault -Name "myvaultname" | Set-AzureRmRecoveryServicesVaultContext
$item = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupItem -BackupManagementType AzureVM -WorkloadType AzureVM -Name "myname"
$latestRecoveryPoint = Get-AzureRmRecoveryServicesBackupRecoveryPoint -Item $item | Sort-Object RecoveryPointTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1
```

If you leave out -Name, you get a list returned with all names.